# Need help on replacing access db file on deployed project in visual studio 2005

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2005

I have a VB based VS2005 appl developed using Access DB a few years back on Windows XP and it has been working fine until moving to Windows 7.  I re-built the solution by changing to the x64 platform also at the sametime modified the Access DB a bit resulting in a new Access DB file to be included in the solution.  When I debug in VS2005, I have the new version of DB residing in my project\x86\Release folder and successfully access this new version.

Problem is that once I create the solution for deployment, the deployed application kept on opening the OLD version of the access database (mdb) file.  I was not able to find where is it opening the old version of DB from even after I removed the mdb from the installed folder. I have been a lot of digging and research on web and not able to find out how to solve this problem.

Can someone please help to tell me how I can have my deployed appl to open the new version of DB ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not allowing for virtualisation - do you know about this? For security reasons after XP (Vista onwards) Microsoft doesn't allow writing to the Programs folder and if it encounters an application attempting to do this makes a copy of the files trying to be written to (in your case an Access database) and places it somewhere (can't remember exactly where at the moment) hidden from casual user.

For example, if you look at the database on your Win 7 machine in the same location at your .exe file I should think you will find it is unused - and since it was installed on the machine the OS has been redirecting requests to read/write to your database to the virtualised copy it created for you.

So, first of all find this other copy (sorry I'm currently on a mac and can't remember the location) and see if that contains data that your application is creating. Then try substituting your new database (making a a copy of your old one first of course) and seeing if your application is reading/writing to it OK.

Then it is a matter of handling replacement of databases during application installation.

However, you should give serious consideration to placing your database in a location which is not virtualised!